# Add Custom Control to DataGridViewCell

Tags: c#, datagridview, custom-controls

I create a custom control inherited from Windows.System.Forms.Controls.

This is my code of this control:

```
   public partial class MonthEventComponent : Control
    {
        private Color couleur;
        private Label labelEvenement;

        public MonthEventComponent(Color couleur_c, String labelEvenement_c )
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.couleur = couleur_c;
            this.labelEvenement.Text = labelEvenement_c;
            this.labelEvenement.ForeColor = couleur;
            this.labelEvenement.BackColor = Color.White;
            this.labelEvenement.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            this.labelEvenement.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.Controls.Add(labelEvenement);
        }

        public MonthEventComponent()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.couleur = Color.Black;
            this.labelEvenement = new Label();
            this.labelEvenement.ForeColor = couleur;
            this.labelEvenement.BackColor = Color.White;
            this.labelEvenement.Text = "Evénement Initialiser";
            this.labelEvenement.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            this.labelEvenement.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            this.Controls.Add(labelEvenement);

        }


        protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnClick(e);

            MessageBox.Show("Click");
        }

    }
```

I would like to insert this control or multiple of this control on a DataGridViewCell but i don't know how to do this.

Thank you in advance for your answer,

Best Regards,

PS: I'm french, i'm apologize for any can of language errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would assume you are using Winforms?

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx?PHPSESSID=o1fb21liejulfgrptbmi9dec92) is an MSDN tutorial on how to host a control in a Winforms `DataGridViewCell`.

From the tutorial:

> The DataGridView control provides
>   several column types, enabling your
>   users to enter and edit values in a
>   variety of ways. If these column types
>   do not meet your data-entry needs,
>   however, you can create your own
>   column types with cells that host
>   controls of your choosing. To do this,
>   you must define classes that derive
>   from DataGridViewColumn and
>   DataGridViewCell. You must also define
>   a class that derives from Control and
>   implements the
>   IDataGridViewEditingControl interface.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will see this.