# How to embed a ListView in a winform DataGridView control

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

We have a WinForm application developed in C# VS 2010 .Net Frame work 3.5. On a window Form we want to display data in a nested DataGridView as given in the figure below. Further it would be nice if we can have expand and collapse features as well.

[image]

Comment: This should be tagged `c#` and `.net` , not `c`!

Comment: My apologies I choose c by mistake; corrected to C#

Comment: I know it's not the same, as it's not listview, but here is a solution for having listBox in dataGridView cell:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24180/DataGridView-Control-with-ListBox

Comment: In addition to  fishmong3r's code have a look these questions: [Add Custom Control to DataGridViewCell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647447/add-custom-control-to-datagridviewcell) and [Display user control in DatagridViewCell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920555/display-user-control-in-datagridviewcell)

Comment: [Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730881%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is also a nice introduction.  One of the questions it raises is this: Just want do you want to do with the ListView?? It it for display only or should it work as an edit control?