# How to host a custom control in DataGridView winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have made a custom control , a range slider with two thumbs which accept two properties from and to.

I want this control to be displayed in a datagridview and bind it to some list from behind.

Whatever info i get on internet is related to some combo box or text control as custom control, how can i host this type of control.

My control inherits from Control class and creates a customized slider.

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-host-controls-in-windows-forms-datagridview-cells, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730881%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. i think, this is a right reason for move to WPF.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Custom Control to DataGridViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647447/add-custom-control-to-datagridviewcell)